# NetLogo: Can agents own lists?

Tags: list, netlogo, agents

I have a NetLogo model of taxis that pick up passengers and take them to their destinations.  My current definition of the taxi breed is as follows:

```
taxis-own [
  route                     ; List of destinations in order, each an x y pair
  destin_x                  ; Coordinates of the taxis current destination
  destin_y
  trip_distance             ; Distance of current trip in Netlogo cells = 100 meters 
  speed                     ; Travel speed in Netlogo cells = 100 meters per minute
  time_left                 ; Time left in current trip until arrival
  status                    ; Waiting ; Picking Up ; Psngr Boarding; En Route ; Psngr Alighting ; Dropping off
  vmt                       ; Vehicle miles traveled
]
```

*destin_x* and *destin_y* are the x and y coordinates respectively of the taxi's current destination.

I would like to store within each taxi a route, or a list of destinations for each taxi.  I.e. [[x1 y1],[x2 y2][x3 y3]...].

Can an agent own a list structure such as this?  Can I use list commands, such as *lput*, within an *ask* command for an agent?  Is there an alternative way of solving this problem?

So far my attempt to do this is not working.  See below:

```
to hail-taxi ;
  let available-taxis taxis with [status = "waiting"] ; Create a set of available taxis
  let hailing-psngrs psngrs with [status = "hailing"] ; Create list of hailing passengers
  foreach sort-by [ [wait_time] of ?1 > [wait_time] of ?2] hailing-psngrs [
    ask ? [
      let free-taxi min-one-of available-taxis [distance myself] ; Find the closest available taxi
      let picked-taxi free-taxi
      if ( picked-taxi != nobody )[
        set status "waiting"
        create-link-with picked-taxi
        ask picked-taxi [
          set status "picking up"
          set available-taxis taxis with [status = "waiting"] ; Revise set of available taxis
; NEXT LINE DOES NOT WORK
          lput list ( [xcor] of myself [ycor] of myself ) route
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

end

Answer (score 2):

> Can an agent own a list structure such as this?

Yes.

> Can I use list commands, such as lput, within an ask command for an agent?

Yes.

```
; NEXT LINE DOES NOT WORK
lput list ( [xcor] of myself [ycor] of myself ) route
```

How about:

```
set route lput [ list xcor ycor ] of myself route
```

I think you may have been a bit confused by the placement of the parenthesis for [`list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list). They usually go around the whole expression (e.g., `(list a b c d)`). In this case, since there are only two arguments, you don't even need parenthesis.

Comment: also a missing `set route ...` before the `lput` yes?

Comment: Thanks!  My problem was the missing `set route` before the `lput` as @SethTisue noted.